# xDebug on Zend Server CE under Windows XP

Tags: php, zend-server, xdebug

I have Zend Server installed on my Windows XP development machine, installed when I was naive and didn't know that Eclipse was going to become so suck so badly for PHP development.

I've made the upgrade to Netbeans, but for debugging they only support xDebug. To be fair I've never used "proper" debuggers before, but other folks have raved about them so I thought I'd give it a try.

I followed some [directions on the Zend forum](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=553) about how to install xDebug on Zend server, disabling Zend Debugger in the process.

The xDebug "custom installation instructions" wizard tells me that my PHP was compiled with an unsupported compiler (MS VC8), and won't let me download anything. I tried a couple of the other xDebug binaries, but they just refused to load. So I'm left without a debugger option. Does anyone know how I can change the compiler of the php version I have installed so I can use a debugger in Netbeans? or how else i can get xDebug to install on Zend Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this instruction: [here](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=553)

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I'm using php 5.3.1, so that's not much use, which is why I mentioned the link above. I'm going to try to upgrade Zend Server as there's a new version out - to see if it's been compiled with a more suitable compiler. I'll report back here when I have.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since Zend Server's been updated (v5.0.3) - I had another try using the "tailored install" wizard - and it seems they're using a supported compiler now.

It all "just worked".